Full contents list of Lego gears boxed set 802 (unknown year)
Is there a definitive complete list of what should be inside one of these boxed sets?

In particular, pins, rods/axles, bricks, clips, and other general accessories (including their quantities)?
I know that there should be:

4 x red
3 x blue
2 x yellow

but what about the other, smaller, parts?

Please note that the box above differs from the 1970 box (see below) - the image is subtly different - so I don't know if that makes a difference. I also don't know what year the box (in the above image) represents.


For questions like this, check a site like bricklink or brickset or rebrickable (links go directly to the inventories for the set you're interested in).

From Brickset.com - 802: Gear Supplement:

